# MySQL UNION on same table with two WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table `alerts`

```
date | alert | status | sentDate | id
```

In this table, after I have sent the alert, I set the status to '`sent`' and set the sent date. By default the status is '`not`' (which means it has not been sent yet).

Now, I want to get the last sentDate, I can get this using the following query

```
SELECT sentDate FROM alerts WHERE id = someid AND status = 'sent' Order by date desc limit 1;
```

Also, I want to get the latest alert which has not been sent, I am using this query

```
SELECT date, alert FROM alerts WHERE id = someid AND status = 'not' order by date asc limit 1;
```

Is it possible to do this in one query? perhaps using UNION. I have tried to apply UNION/UNION ALL on these two queries but it gives me error.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to have the same number of columns to use UNION.

Comment: Why would id be 'id' ?!?!

Comment: The columns of the query must be the same in both queries.

Comment: @Strawberry just an example, id is some id in integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
max(CASE WHEN status = 'sent' THEN DATE END) AS sentDate,
max(CASE WHEN status = 'not' THEN DATE END) AS notSentDate 
FROM alerts WHERE id = someid
```

You can try above query.

It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try this :

```
SELECT MAX(t.sentDate) AS sentDate, MAX(t.date) AS date, MAX(alert) AS alert
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(sentDate) AS  sentDate, "" AS date, "" AS alert
    FROM alerts 
    WHERE id = someid 
    AND status = 'sent'

    UNION 

    SELECT "" AS sentDate, date, alert 
    FROM alerts 
    WHERE id = someid 
    AND status = 'not'
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

```
    SELECT 
    (Select date from alerts where id= someid AND status='not' 
ORDER by date DESC limit 1) latestNotSentDate, 
    (Select date from alerts where id= someid AND status='sent' 
ORDER BY date DESC limit 1) latestSentDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

The number of columns have to be the same in your queries, try this :

```
SELECT sentDate,'' FROM alerts WHERE id = 'id' AND status = 'sent' Order by date desc limit 1;

UNION

SELECT date, alert FROM alerts WHERE id = 'id' AND status = 'not' order by date asc limit 1;
```

In addition, i think the status is irrelevant, this information is given by the presence of a sentDate.

I think you can write  :

```
SELECT sentDate,'' FROM alerts WHERE id = 'id' AND sentDate is not null Order by date desc limit 1;

    UNION

    SELECT date, alert FROM alerts WHERE id = 'id' AND sentDate is NULL order by date asc limit 1;
```